# Jest globalSetup option not working

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to make a function called loadFixtures available to all Jest tests.

I have the following line within the jest config object inside package.json:

```
"globalSetup": "<rootDir>/src/test/js/config/setup-globals.js"
```

setup-globals.js contains:

```
module.exports = function() {
    function loadFixtures(filename) {
        console.info('loadFixtures is working');
    }
}
```

Within my tests I have, for example:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    loadFixtures('tooltip-fixture.html');
});
```

However when I run Jest I get the following for each test:

```
ReferenceError: loadFixtures is not defined
```

I verified that the setup-globals.js file is definitely being found and loaded in by Jest before the tests execute.

Can anyone assist in identifying where I've gone wrong here? I've spent pretty much an entire day trying to debug without luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be using `setupFiles` and not `globalSetup`.

```
// jest config
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/src/test/js/config/setup-globals.js"
]
```

then `src/test/js/config/setup-globals.js`:

```
global.loadFixtures(filename) {
  console.info('loadFixtures is working');
}
```

references: https://medium.com/@justintulk/how-to-mock-an-external-library-in-jest-140ac7b210c2

Answer (score 7):

If you bootstrapped your application using `npx create-react-app` (CRA), you do not need to add the `setupFiles` key under your `jest` key in the `package.json` file (CRA prevents overriding that key).

what you simply need to do is to add the file `setupTests.js` in the root of your `SRC` folder, and populate it with the snippet below:

```js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({
  adapter: new Adapter(),
});
```

> remember you must have earlier installed the right versions of `enzyme` and `enzyme-adapter-react`

CRA has been wired to automatically load the `setupTests.js` file in the `src` folder if it exists. Hence after adding these, you can then go over to your test and do `import {shallow} from enzyme` without triggering an error.

if you are not using `Create-react-app`, all you need to do, in addition to adding the file above to your `src` folder is to add the key `setupFiles` into the `jest` key in your package.json. it should look like this:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js'],
  }
```

and you are good to go.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a function in a different scope. How about you create a separate module and import it directly in your test files. Or if you really want to define it in the global scope, try using the following code in your `setup-globals.js` file.

```js
module.exports = function() {
    global.loadFixtures = function(filename) {
        console.info('loadFixtures is working');
    }
}
```